# Nord VPN, can it be used?

Tags: vpn

I need to know if Nord VPN service can be used in Ubuntu 14.04? I got the subscrption while on WIndows8 but had a hard drive failure and loaded 14.04 onto the new HD. Now I need to see if I can get this service up and running on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can, first install this client

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

Then change to its dir

```
cd /etc/openvpn
```

Download OpenVPN configuration files with command

```
sudo wget https://nordvpn.com/api/files/zip
```

In case you will get `ERROR: The certificate of`nordvpn.com’ is not trusted.`, please install`ca-certificates` package with command

```
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Extract `config.zip` with command

```
sudo unzip zip
```

Remove files which will be no longer used

```
sudo rm zip
```

To see the list of all available servers, simply enter `ls -al` command and it will print full configuration file list.

Choose a server which you would like to connect to.

Start OpenVPN with a chosen configuration by entering

```
sudo openvpn file name
```

(for example: `sudo openvpn vpn_at_nordvpn_tcp.ovpn`).

OpenVPN will ask you for credentials, so simply enter those in with your NordVPN account credentials.

You have successfully connected to VPN. To disconnect from the OpenVPN connection simply open terminal and type `Ctrl + C` command.

This is adapted from the [NordVPN website](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/), this seems the best way to do it but two alternatives are provided there, if you need something different.

Comment: Followed the steps. No error messages from openvpn but my network is not connected to the vpn server in the ovpn server. What might have gone wrong, Mark?